# Postgresql IPC: MessageQueueSend delaying queries from nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am testing postgresql with a nodejs backend server, using Pg npm module to query the database. The issue I am having is that when I run a particular query directly on the postgres database table using  query tool on pgAdmin4, the data is fetched within 5 seconds. But the same query when requested from the backend through my nodejs server, the process is split between parallel workers and a client backend using IPC: messagequeuesend, this runs for almost 17minutes before return the data. I can't understand why the same query is fast using query tool, it just processes it fast but the one coming from my server has to delay. Is there a way to increase the priority for queries coming from backend to run like it was queried inside pgAdmin. I noticed when I check pg_stat_activity, there is an application value for the query when using query tool, but when the same query comes from the nodejs server the application value is null. I do not seem to understand why its like this, i have been searching every community for answers to this for the past 5 days, and there is no question or answer for this. Please any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

I tried running a query from the backend, but its split using IPC processes and result comes in after 17 minutes, the same query takes only 5 seconds to return a result inside pgAdmin query tool

Comment: Use `lob_min_duration_statement` and `auto_explain` to capture the statements and their plans. Then add this information to the question.

Comment: okay will do that and revert, thanks